# Two Errors in this code: Why and significance

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, minitoc

Overleaf tells me that there are 2 Errors in this code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[tight, italian]{minitoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\newcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
%\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
%\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@}

\newif{\ifTOC}

\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[1]{\ifTOC\tikzmark{#1}\fi}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\newcommand*{\arabicdec}[1]{\the\numexpr\value{#1}-1\relax}
%\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabicdec{chapter}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabicdec{section}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\makeatletter
% copied from book
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
\vspace{-10pt}% or whatever
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{\color{red}{\Huge{\textbf{ALGEBRA LINEARE}}}}
\author{\color{blue}{\Huge{\textbf{???}}}}
\date{27 Febbraio 2021 $-$ xx Mese Anno}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\dominitoc

\TOCtrue
\tableofcontents
\TOCfalse

\newpage

\section*{PREFAZIONE GENERALE}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}PREFAZIONE GENERALE}

\mainmatter

\chapter{NOTAZIONI PRELIMINARI}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip
\pagestyle{plain}

\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxa}}%
\section[??\string\hspace{80pt}]{??}
\subsection[???\string\hspace{48pt}]{???}
\subsubsection[????\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxb}]{????}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{5pt}\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxa)+(-2pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxb)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}
      

\part[FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE]%
{\huge\color{red}{FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE}}

\section*{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}
%\Large{Inserire una Prefazione}

\chapter{One}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip


\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxA}}%
\section[One.One\string\hspace{130pt}]{One.One}
\subsection[One.One.One\string\hspace{78pt}]{One.One.One}
\subsubsection[Very long Expression\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxB}]{One.One.One.One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxA)+(-2pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxB)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}%
  
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxC}}%
\section[One.One\string\hspace{116pt}]{One.One}
\subsection[One.One.One\string\hspace{64pt}]{One.One.One}
\subsubsection[One.One.One.One\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxD}]{One.One.One.One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxC)+(-5pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxD)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}%
      
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxE}}%
\section[One.One\string\hspace{116pt}]{One.One}
\subsection[One.One.One\string\hspace{64pt}]{One.One.One}
\subsubsection[One.One.One.One\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxF}]{One.One.One.One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxE)+(-5pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxF)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}%
      

\end{document}
```

The Errors are these:

(double) LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. (output.toc, 9), this is:

```
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 ...FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE}{3}{part.1}
                                                  %
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

Why and what does it mean?

(Neverthless I get compilation of this code)

(If you need a photo of compilation, I'll edit my question adding a photo)

Thank you so much

**First Edit:** Reading comments, this code produces:

[image: 4Strutboxes]

and without this part

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{5pt}
\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same page
{\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxa)+(-2pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle ($(pic cs:TOCboxb)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}
```

I have this compilation that I dislike (neverthless I have no more errors)

[image: 3Strutboxes]

(Please note the absence of the `strutbox` at the first part of `toableofcontents`)

Comment: Add `\string\par` at the end of the first `\addtocontents` just before your `\part`: `\addtocontents{toc}{... \string\par}`

Comment: Thank you. I solved!

Comment: Why defining strange tags?

Comment: @egreg If you have a better solution then mine, please publy it! Thank you. What are these strange tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by **Werner** and **Robin Hellmer**'s help a better solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[tight, italian]{minitoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\newcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
%\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
%\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@}

\newif{\ifTOC}

\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[1]{\ifTOC\tikzmark{#1}\fi}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\newcommand*{\arabicdec}[1]{\the\numexpr\value{#1}-1\relax}
%\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabicdec{chapter}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabicdec{section}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\makeatletter
% copied from book
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
\vspace{-10pt}% or whatever
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{\color{red}{\Huge{\textbf{ALGEBRA LINEARE}}}}
\author{\color{blue}{\Huge{\textbf{???}}}}
\date{27 Febbraio 2021 $-$ xx Mese Anno}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\dominitoc

\TOCtrue
\tableofcontents
\TOCfalse

\newpage

\section*{PREFAZIONE GENERALE}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}PREFAZIONE GENERALE}

\mainmatter

\chapter{NOTAZIONI PRELIMINARI}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip
\pagestyle{plain}

\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxa}}%
\section[??\string\hspace{80pt}]{??}
\subsection[???\string\hspace{48pt}]{???}
\subsubsection[????\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxb}]{????}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-25pt}
\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same page
{\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxa)+(-2pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle ($(pic cs:TOCboxb)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}\string\par}
      

\part[FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE]%
{\huge\color{red}{FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE}}

\section*{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}
%\Large{Inserire una Prefazione}

\chapter{One}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip


\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxA}}%
\section[One.One\string\hspace{130pt}]{One.One}
\subsection[One.One.One\string\hspace{78pt}]{One.One.One}
\subsubsection[Very long Expression\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxB}]{One.One.One.One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxA)+(-2pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxB)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}%
  
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxC}}%
\section[One.One\string\hspace{116pt}]{One.One}
\subsection[One.One.One\string\hspace{64pt}]{One.One.One}
\subsubsection[One.One.One.One\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxD}]{One.One.One.One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxC)+(-5pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxD)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}%
      
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxE}}%
\section[One.One\string\hspace{116pt}]{One.One}
\subsection[One.One.One\string\hspace{64pt}]{One.One.One}
\subsubsection[One.One.One.One\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxF}]{One.One.One.One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxE)+(-5pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxF)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}%
      

\end{document}
```

This is the main part that solved my two Errors:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-25pt}
\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same page
{\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxa)+(-2pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle ($(pic cs:TOCboxb)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}\string\par}
```

Thank you again

Comment: If someone has a better solution then mine, please publy it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

It seems like a problem in how the compilation process is done as when compiling using `latexmk`, I get the errors:

[image]

And the errors in the `.toc` file does not make any sense in why they occurr:

[image]

Meanwhile compiling with `pdflatex` a couple of times gives the result which you are looking for without any errors.

**Previous answer:**

Your little `\addtocontents` with `tikz` content is making you the trouble.

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{5pt}\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxa)+(-2pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxb)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}
```

Remove it and your problem is gone. But I am not sure why you have that line as it isn't working correctly as it doesn't add anything to the actual doocument.

Comment: Eh no. I need of that part of code... It's true that I have no more problems... But the solution is another... What is it? Actually, This part of code add a strutbox at toc. I belief that I must add a photo...

Comment: @Puck When I compiled it, that code did not add anything to the document. But that one is the one causing you problems and thereby you may have to fix it to work correctly.

Comment: I edited my code. Do you mange to see the difference (See my two photos)?

Comment: @Puck Much clearer now. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Robin Hellmer, about your edit I'm using pdflatex, but the result is the same when I use LaTeX. I found a better solution, can you see it?